# Ember.js ArrayController hooked into CollectionView: How to update object properties in 'content' array?

Tags: controller, ember.js, collectionview

ember newjack here. Hooking an ArrayController into a CollectionView.

```
// the ArrayController
App.Entities = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: Ember.A([
            {id: 1, name: "item 1"},
            {id: 2, name: "item 2"},
            ...
            {id: n, name: "item n"}
        ])
});

// the CollectionView
myView = Ember.CollectionView.create(
    contentBinding: "App.Entities",
    tagName: 'ul',
    itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
        template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{view.content.name}}')
    })
).appendTo("mySelector");
```

Which, as expected creates a nice `ul` with my properties.
As well, all array-level operations such as popping, pushing and reversing work fabulously:

```
App.Entities.reverseObjects(); // Works!
App.Entities.popObject(); // Works!
```

However, I can't seem to update a property *inside* the array:

```
App.Entities.objectAtContent(0).name = "new name" // I know this is wrong
```

Anecdotally, it works if I perform an array operation afterwards:

```
App.Entities.reverseObjects(); // change is picked up!
```

So the question: How to update properties INSIDE an ArrayController (And make sure bindings are updated?)

By the way, I've tried everything I can think of.. such as myView.rerender() etc but I know I'm just doing something wrong because it's going against the way things *should* work.

Comment: Doing some more digging around, I notice I can *replace* an object in the array:

    `App.Entities.insertAt(2,{name: "new name", id=99});`
or
    `App.Entities.replaceContent(2, 1,[{name: "new name", id=99}]);`
But.. it does feel like overkill just to change a property..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `App.Entities.objectAt(0).set('name', "New name")` and let me know if this works...The Array must contain Ember Objects in order for the bindings to work for the changes made

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. unfortunately: `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'set'`

Comment: Wondering if it may have something to do with _childViews?

Comment: YO!! I got the answer, thank you so much for leading me to the right thing! So in order for this to work, you have to make sure the objects in the data array are *Ember* objects.. and then you can use a binding on @each.name to ensure they are picked up by computed properties!

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot to mention that you need to use Ember Objects for the set & get, apparently for the bindings to work, updated the answer...Glad to know it worked :)

Comment: Please read the entire comment thread to get the answer. TL;DR: You need to observe properties on Ember.Objects for binding to work.. it doesn't work on vanilla objects. Man how I remember the challenges of starting in Ember :)

Comment: @AlexKessaris been there :) It took so long to accept answer though :P